# match query no has result for custom analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two index:

First:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/first/' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer":"spanish"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Second:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/second/' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
             "analyzer":"spanish_custom"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "spanish_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwordsPath":  "spanish_stop_custom.txt" 
        },
        "spanish_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "spanish"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "spanish_custom": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "spanish_stop",
            "spanish_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

I insert some document for both index:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/first/product' -d '
{
  "name": "Hidratante"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/second/product' -d '
{
  "name": "Hidratante"
}'
```

i checked tokens for the field name:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/first/_analyze?field=name' -d 'hidratante'

{"tokens":[{"token":"hidratant","start_offset":0,"end_offset":10,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1}]}



curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/second/_analyze?field=name' -d 'hidratante'

{"tokens":[{"token":"hidrat","start_offset":0,"end_offset":10,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1}]}
```

I want search for 'hidratant' and give results in both index, but i got results only first index

My Query:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/first/_search' -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "hidratant",
      "fields" : [ "name"],
      "type" : "phrase_prefix",
      "operator" : "AND",
      "prefix_length" : 3,
      "tie_breaker": 1
    }
  }
}
'
```

First index result:

```
{"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":0.5945348,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"product","_id":"AVPxjvpRDl8qAEgsMFMu","_score":0.5945348,"_source":
{
  "name": "Hidratante"
}},{"_index":"test","_type":"product","_id":"AVPxkYbKDl8qAEgsMFMv","_score":0.5945348,"_source":
{
  "name": "Hidratante"
}}]}}
```

Second index result:

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

**Why the second index no has return  result?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question above, for second index the tokens being generated for the term `Hidratante`are:

```
{"tokens":[{"token":"hidrat","start_offset":0,"end_offset":10,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1}]}
```

There is a concept of `search analyzer` which comes in when you perform search operation. According to the documentation:

> By default, queries will use the analyzer defined in the field mapping while searching.

So when you run `phrase_prefix` query , same custom analyzer created by you will act on `name` field in second index.

Since you are searching for keyword : `hidratant`

It gets analyzed as :

For first Index:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/first/_analyze?field=name' -d 'hidratant'`

```
{
"tokens": [
  {
     "token": "hidratant",
     "start_offset": 3,
     "end_offset": 12,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 1
    }
  ]
 }
```

i.e why you get result in first index.

For second index:

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/second/_analyze?field=name' -d 'hidratant'`

```
 {
 "tokens": [
  {
     "token": "hidratant",
     "start_offset": 3,
     "end_offset": 12,
     "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
     "position": 1
   }
  ]
 }
```

The token generated while searching is `hidratant` but it was `hidrat` while indexing. That's why you don't get any result in second case.

Comment: Now, I can understand! Thanks!